# Different languages in Android without resource files

Tags: android

I have a question regarding mutiple languages for Android Apps. I know it is common pratice to use resource files for your strings (Android Studio always reminds you of this if you have forgotten). However, I am wondering how to do this for the following two elements:

1. Pictures that have different language contents
2. String variables within a class that are not explicitly defined in the XML layout file

How would you handle these issues? I'd appreciate every comment.

Update: Here is an example of a String variable that I use in the code (but not in a XML-Layout file). It is the string 'Comment' in an AlertDialog:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Comment");

        // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
            input.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
            input.setSingleLine(false);
            input.setLines(3);
            input.setText(comment_Text);
            builder.setView(input);


        // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    comment_Text = input.getText().toString();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can localize your drawables as well.

You can do this by creating a folder for a specific language, the same way as you would localize the string resources.

Example of a drawable for the default locale:

```
res/drawable-hdpi/country_flag.png
```

Example of a drawable for a different locale (es_ES)

```
res/drawable-es-rES-hdpi/country_flag.png
```

For more information please check out the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Concerning you second question; your classes should also make use of the string resources, don't use hardcoded strings.

An example of how to do this:

In this case the string resource file would contain:

```
<string name="title_comment">Comment</string>
<string name="button_ok">OK</string>
<string name="button_cancel">Cancel</string>
```

The code for your AlertDialog would then look like this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.title_comment);

            final EditText input = new EditText(this);

            input.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
            input.setSingleLine(false);
            input.setLines(3);
            input.setText(comment_Text);
            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    comment_Text = input.getText().toString();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer DennisN. How can my classes make use of the string resources? Shall every String in the class be defined as a String resource?

Comment: If you are using the string in your UI, it should indeed make use of the resources. This will make localization possible. If you are merely using the string in your code, consider using an "enum class" or "const val". If you can give me an example of where you are using the string I can give you a more precise recommendation.

Comment: Thanks DennisN for your answer. I indeed use the String only in a code. I have edited my original post by adding an illustrative example.

Comment: Since you're going to show an AlertDialog in your UI, the strings "Comment", "OK" and "Cancel" should all be added to your string resources.  This way they are easy to maintain and it will be possible to display the title and buttons on the AlertDialog in different languages as well. I am going to update my answer to give you an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot DennisN for your answer and effort. I do not want to create a XML layout file for the AlertDialog. I just want to create the AlertDialog within the class because it is too time consuming and complicated for me to have a XML layout file for everything

Comment: You don't need to create a layout file, just the file res/values/strings.xml, you will be able to use the strings in this file throughout your entire project.

Comment: Thanks a lot DennisN for your answer. Now I understand what you mean.

Comment: I still have another question regarding the pictures in the different languages. I use a tool in Android studio that generated the different resolutions xdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi out of one image and stores them into the right folders for the images (e.g. xdpi folder). If I now define different folders for the different languages (as you suggested) I don't think that it will work with the tool. This would mean that I would have to create all images sepeartely for every resultion which is quite uncomfortable. Is there a way how I can do this automatically?

Comment: Any comment about how to combine the different folders for the different languages with the tool that creates the pictures for the different resolutions? I'd be quite thankful for further comments.

Comment: Hi guys, I still have not figured out how to handle the different folders for the different languages. If I have a picture for two languages, how can I automaticcaly create the corresponding pictures with different solutions (xdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi  e.g.) and put them into the right folders? I'd really appreciate every input.

Comment: Does nobody know how to do this?

Comment: What is your advice regarding the automatic creation of figures for the different languages with different resolutions?

Comment: Regarding the pictures. If I want to have also German pictures, do I have to create folders named like 'drawable-de-rDE-hdpi', 'drawable-de-rDE-xhdpi' etc.?

Comment: Regarding your other question, I don't think there is an "out of the box" way to generate images into the localized folders in Android Studio. What you can do is place the images inside the drawable folder and of course inside the localized drawable folders. An example of a localized drawable folder would be drawable-de-rDE. Android will then scale the image itself. This way you don't need to create hdpi, xhdpi ... folders. To answer your latest question: yes, that's how you should name the folders.

Comment: Another option, especially if you need images that scale very good, is to look into Vector Drawables. Those are generated by Android Studio or some other tool from a .svg image. You can save all your Vector Drawables inside the drawable folder for each locale.

Comment: Thanks a lot DennisN for your comment. Basically I tried it with one folder for several resolutions and let Anrdroid scale the immages many times. The results were always extremely bad. This is why I want to use pictures with different resolutions. This worked a lot better. So I am then going to create the different folders. This should work.

Comment: Okay, great! If you find it too much of a hassle, you can always generate svg images and let Android Studio or some other tool convert them into Vector Drawables. It works very good and is my preferred way to use images in my apps.

Comment: Thanks DennisN for your comment. How do I basically 'let Android Studio or some other tool convert them into Vector Drawables' as you said? And might this not be a problem regarding the computational time for scaling the vector images?

Comment: Hi DennisN. Would you advice me to use your vector methods? I think it is better to use different resolutions (at least someone told me that in Stackexchange some time ago). Why do you think it is better to use your vector method? I'd be quite happy if you could share your experience.

Comment: Hi DennisN. Do you have any comments on my last two comments? I would really appreciate your feedback as you have a lot more experience than I do

Comment: Any comment? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Vectors have the advantage of being scalable without losing image quality.  You can let Android Studio convert a .svg file to a Vector Drawable by right clicking the "res" directory and then selecting "new" > "Vector Asset". I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks DennisN for your answer. But for that I need vector graphics which I do not have and this might affect the performace of the app when you scale the imges all the time.